# 1467 Failed to read auto-increment value from storage engine, query was: INSERT INTO `catalog_category_product

Tags: magento2

When adding a new product through product import from admin then getting below error-

SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1467 Failed to read auto-increment value from storage engine, query was: INSERT INTO `catalog_category_product` (`product_id`,`category_id`,`position`) VALUES (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `product_id` = VALUES(`product_id`), `category_id` = VALUES(`category_id`)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Follow below steps to resolve the import issue:

1. Check in catalog_category_product table for duplicate value. If any duplicate value found then remove them from table.
2. Run below query to set auto-increment id of table

ALTER TABLE `catalog_category_product`  AUTO_INCREMENT = last_increment_id + 1;

Answer (score 0):

Need to increase the size of datatype from int to bigint of auto-increment column. You can use below code to increase datatype-

In app/code/vendor_name/module_name/etc/db_schema.xml

[image]